# Singleton pattern used on another class

Tags: c++, singleton

So I am trying to implement a program that has a scoreboard and two players, I am trying to make it so that the two players share a scoreboard using the singleton pattern. However when I try to use methods on the global scoreboard defined in the player classes I always get a "run failed" message.

These are my two header files, I can provide the full implementation if it's necessary.

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include "scoreboard.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


class Player{
private:
        std::ifstream file1;
        std::ifstream file2;
        static Scoreboard* _game;
    public:
        static Scoreboard* Game();
        void makeMove(const char,const std::string);
};


#endif

#ifndef SCOREBOARD_H
#define SCOREBOARD_H

class Scoreboard{
    private:
        int aWin;
        int bWin;
        int LIMIT;
        int curCounter;

    public:
        void resetWins();
        void addWin(char);
        void makeMove(const int, char);
        void startGame(const int, const int);
        int getWin(char);
        int getTotal();
        int getLimit();
};

#endif  /* SCOREBOARD_H */
```

in player.cc

```
Scoreboard* Player::_game = 0;

Scoreboard* Player::Game(){
    if (_game = 0)
    {
        _game = new Scoreboard;
        _game->resetWins();
    }
    return _game;
}
```

Along with the makeMove method

Comment: Do you initialize `static Scoreboard* Player::_game`?

Comment: did you write `Scoreboard* Player::_game` in the .cpp file ?

Comment: Is there a reason you used a static pointer instead of a static variable?

Comment: yes I initialized it in player.cc

Comment: I thought that I needed to use a static pointer for this to work

Comment: The scoreboard class itself should store a reference to one, and only one instance of Scoreboard, which you access with a getInstance() method

Comment: @AndyG That is one way to do it, but as he is really just trying to share the scoreboard with the instances of `Player`, he *can* do it this way as well (which would potentially make the `Scoreboard` class more useful).

Comment: @AndyG How do I the scoreboard instance with players then? Do I create a pointer to scoreboard within my player class and then use getInstance() on that?

Comment: The way I am doing it now doesnt seem to allow me to use methods from scoreboard with my global instance of scoreboard

Comment: @ZacHowland: Yes, this way works, but it's not really a Singleton design pattern because you can easily create multiple instances of Scoreboard. The invariant of a proper Singleton is that the class enforces only one instance of itself.

Comment: @user1985251: Here's a good tutorial on the Singleton (and why some people hate it) http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html

Comment: @AndyG Understood.  My point was more that he isn't really implmenting the singleton pattern (but rather just forcing a single instance of scoreboard for all instances of players).

Comment: [OT]: With higher warning level, your compiler would warn you about this error. Instead of using static variable, you may pass it as parameter of Player::MakeMove, or use a simple reference to an existing Scoreboard (pass the reference in the constructor).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Scoreboard` instance does not need to be a pointer:

```
static Scoreboard _game;
// ...
static Scoreboard& Game() { return _game; }
```

Or alternatively, just leave out the class declaration of `_game`:

```
// you can either make this function static or non-static
Scoreboard& Game()
{
    static Scoreboard game; // but this variable MUST be static
    return game;
}
```

That will do the same thing without the memory management issues.

This will create a single instance of `Scoreboard` for all `Players`.  If you only ever wanted to have a *single* instance of `Scoreboard` (e.g. if you had a `Referees` class that needed to see the scoreboard as well), you would modify your scoreboard class:

```
class Scoreboard
{
private:
    // all your data members
    Scoreboard() {} // your default constructor - note that it is private!
public:
    // other methods
    Scoreboard& getInstance()
    {
        static Scoreboard instance;
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Then, to access it in your other classes, you would include the scoreboard header and use it as:

```
#include "Scoreboard.h"

void my_func()
{
    Scoreboard& scoreboard = Scoreboard::getInstance();
    scoreboard.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Suggest moving `_game` into the `Game()` function itself (still as a static).

Comment: @Chad Added that as an alternative.

Comment: The advantage with *static pointer* over *static object* is that he has more control for when the constructor/destructor is called... Which may be important with interleaving static variables (the hell of static)...

Comment: @Jarod42 In general, yes.  In this case in particular, that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In `Player::Game`, you have written

```
if (_game = 0)
```

that is setting `_game = 0` and evaluating to false, so that you don't actually create the scoreboard. Change it for:

```
if (_game == 0)
```